# How to override ModelNotFoundException in Laravel's Eloquent Models?

Tags: laravel, exception, eloquent

I'm wondering, if it's possible, to throw custom exception, when on some condition/query Laravel's Eloquent model is not found?

For example, if I have a `Page` model, how can I throw my custom, `PageNotFound` exception?

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model {
}
```

This model will throw `ModelNotFoundException` with the given message:

```
No query results for model [App\Page].
```

Comment: To answer the question you asked, you could literally override the `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` methods in each model and instead of throwing a `ModelNotFoundException` you could throw whatever you wanted. However, as mentioned in Tony's answer, you could just call `getModel()` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` try adding the following code to the top of the render function

```
  public function render($request, Exception $e)
        {
            if ($e
                instanceof
                \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) 
            {
              abort(404);
            }

            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
```

**EDIT**
*Once you catch the ModelNotFoundException object, you can call* `getModel()` *on it to get the classname of the model.*

Comment: Yes, I know how to "handle" the exceptions, But I have different types of Models, such as Page, Post and etc. How to found out (without parsing $e->getMessage() of ModelNotFound exception), which Model was not found? 

What I'm asking is, How to throw my own custom exception, when Model not found? 

I could do in my controller to check if query returned any results, and after that throw exception or just do whatever I want to do, but isn't there any simples solution for my question ?

Comment: just call getModel() on ModelNotFoundException object. See my edit

Comment: $e->getModel() method is one, that I didn't know about it. It really didn't answer my question, but it's much more better way, then I was doing it before. Thanks!