# How to Customize Log Format in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, monolog

How can I override how Laravel/Monolog formats Exceptions?

Right now they're coming out like this:

```
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pay.booking_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `seg`.`id` as `segment_id`, ..*snip*.. in /srv/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:729
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(685): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select `seg`.`i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /srv/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(349): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select `seg`.`i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /srv/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1610): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select `seg`.`i...', Array, true)
#3 /srv/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1596): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
```

I want to take the Exception object and format it myself (return a string). I do not want to override/reimplement where the logs go (what file) or anything of that nature.

Using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091701/how-to-override-modelnotfoundexception-in-laravels-eloquent-models) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033125/laravel-5-7-custom-blade-template-for-maintenance-mode-but-not-503-blade-php/54035915#54035915) answers. You can try to override one of those [methods](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L29-L50) in Exception Handler. Just check if `$exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException` before parent's method execution.

Comment: Similar is proposed in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors).

Comment: @Tpojka None of those answer my question. Yes, I can catch the Exception and do something different with it, but that's why I stated specifically that I do not want to deal with the file handling, just the formatting of the message. The magic is buried in that `parent::report`, which uses `$log`, which I assume is an instance of Monolog. But I don't want to override the entire Monolog object, just the formatter.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you *could* extend the LogManager class and replace the Formatter with your own.

I created a new `LogManager` which is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Support\Log;

use Illuminate\Log\LogManager as BaseLogManager;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class LogManager extends BaseLogManager
{
    protected function formatter()
    {
        $format = "%channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra% [%datetime%]\n";

        return tap(new LineFormatter($format, null, true, true), function ($formatter) {
            $formatter->includeStacktraces();
        });
    }
}
```

.. which extends Laravel's base Log Manager, but with an overriden `formatter()`.

You will also notice the format of the message is changed whereby the date is appended to the last part of the string.

The only thing left to do was to bind this into the container rather than the default one. So, in my `AppServiceProvider@register()`, I added this:

```
use App\Support\Log\LogManager;

$this->app->singleton('log', function () {
    return new LogManager($this->app);
});
```

.. and sure enough, the new log format is as such:

```
local.INFO: test   [2019-01-14 04:42:07]
```

You could also take a look at the [LineFormatter class](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php) and see what other things you could possibly do with it.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Close. Is it possible to replace just the [`LineFormatter`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/ebb804e432e8fe0fe96828f30d89c45581d36d07/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php#L68-L112) without extending the entire `LogManager`?

Comment: I think if the LogManager class was composed of the Formatter, it would have been probably possible, but since it's being instantiated right into the `formatter()` method, I am not entirely sure if there'd be an easy way of doing this.